# WinForm WebBrowser control does not support jquery toggle function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, winforms

I have an asp.net web application, where I have used "toggleClass" and "toggle" function. This works absolutely fine in all browsers.

I have another windows app (.Net Framework 4.0) where we need to open this page inside webbrowser control, but this does not work as expected. The toggle part remains in just one state and does not change.

Below is the code for your reference. Please let me know if you need further information.

```
 $('.arrow').on("click", function () {
                $('.arrow-img').toggleClass('rotate');
                $('.arrow-img').toggleClass('rotate2');
                $('#correctCust').toggle(300);
            });
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console to see if you have an js errors?

Comment: Do you have access to the .Net Framework WinForm app code? I can't see why it would work in Internet Explorer but not in the WinForm. If you have access to the code for the program you may want to show that. I may also recomend using webkit .net or gekco for .Net. I can see if I can get you a download for them

Comment: This could be because the WebBrowser control renders using IE6 standards by default (read: awful). You might try FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION to make it render using the latest installed version of Internet Explorer [LINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)